# why counting wrong when i click select all checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a problem. I have some checkbox. I want to select them at once, but counting result is wrong. when If I use firefox, opera then ok but when i use crome,safari, IE then It gives me a wrong result. why? please help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/Taslimkhan/kdEmH/2/

some code I have set here:

```
    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
          $(this).change(updateCount);
        });

        updateCount();

        function updateCount () {
          var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();

          $("#count").text(count);
          $("#status").toggle(count > 0);
        };
      });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, [`.size()` is deprecated.](http://api.jquery.com/size/) Use the `length` property instead.

Second, you probably want to restrict the checkboxes being counted to the ones with the `.case` class:

```
var count = $("input[type=checkbox].case:checked").length;
```

Third, the way your code is written, you should be calling `updateCount()` on the `click` event instead of the `change` event, and you don't need the anonymous function there:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(updateCount);
```

I saved a new revision of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdEmH/8/

Comment: Shouldn't the output be 6, in case when select-all is checked? *At least, it is so in Opera*.

Comment: if that's the desired behavior, then yes. But I have a feeling that isn't what the OP wants. If so, he can just ignore the second point above and not add `.case` to the selector.

Comment: thank you very much. please can you tell me how can i vote you? because i want to vote you. but i dont know how to vote.

Comment: You need 15 reputation to vote. You should see a ▲ above the big number to the left of the answer. If not, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Click is the correct event to capture not change. Also why are you iteratively binding. Replace your document.ready with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").bind('click', function () {
      updateCount();
    });

    updateCount();

    function updateCount () {
        var count = $( "input:checked" ).length;

      $("#count").text(count);
      $("#status").toggle(count > 0);
    };
  });
```

Comment: `$("input").bind('click', function () { updateCount(); });` could be simplified to `$("input").click(updateCount);`, Better yet, the `change` event would be more semantically correct, since the you want to update when the value of the checkbox changes, which may happen when you tab to the checkbox and hit space

Comment: but i want to select all item at once and select all checkbox will not countable

Answer (score 1):

Like Angela said, you should be listening for change events, the click is not guaranteed to be called after the value of the checkbox has changed. Also, the value may change because of other things, like tabbing into the field, and hitting space. It's also important to realize that a change event does not fire after when you set the value of a checkbox programatically, so you have to call updateCount yourself when you set the value programatically, therefore, there's no reason to bind updateCount to the click, just call it when you handle the change event of any of the checkboxes.

Here's a full snippet like what you had, except that I keep the count visible at all times

```
$(function(){
    function updateCount () {
        var count = $("input.case[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        $("#count").text(count);
    }
    updateCount();

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").change(function() {
        $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
        updateCount();
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").change(function(){
        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }
        updateCount();
    });
});
```